# Django Filter specific user's salary within giving date range

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have Two models :

```
class MonthSalary(models.Model):
    month = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.month.year) + '/' + str(self.month.month)

class SalaryPerMonth(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salary_month = models.ForeignKey(MonthSalary, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    main_salary_per_month = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    net_salary_per_month = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["user", "salary_month"], name="all_keys_unique_together")]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.employeedetail.empcode) + ' ' + str(self.net_salary_per_month) + ' USD' + str(
            self.salary_month)
```

In Views I can query all user salaries with :

```
user = request.user
salary_per_month = SalaryPerMonth.objects.filter(user=user)
```

In MonthSalary model I added a bunch of months\years not in order Ex "2022-2,2022-4,2022-1,2021-4" when I filter user's salary by ordering the date "related salary_month field" like so :

```
salary_per_month = SalaryPerMonth.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('salary_month')
```

It's not in order.

Q1 = How how filter by Year ?
Q2 = How to order by month ?

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer to part one of my question "Q2" ordering by Month

All I did is add Meta class:

```
class Meta:
class MonthSalary(models.Model):
    month = models.DateField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-month']


class SalaryPerMonth(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salary_month = models.ForeignKey(MonthSalary, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    main_salary_per_month = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    net_salary_per_month = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-salary_month']
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).